# Detect and prevent duplicate names ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

My problem is just like the title says: I would like to detect and prevent duplicate names in an ArrayList. I can't use any Set method.

Here's my code:

```
private static void kommandoEtt() {

    Kund nyKund = new Kund();

    System.out.print("Name: ");

    nyKund.setNamn(tangentbord.nextLine());

    kundregister.add(nyKund);

}
```

Comment: @Johan Lundström your question is not very clear, good you have tried something beinga  beginner, but pls explain properly so that solution can be provided.

Comment: Iterate and compare, or look at the API docs for the list and see if there's something like `contains`.

Answer (score 3):

Without using a `Set`, you can avoid adding two of the same objects to a `List` using the `List#contains(Object)` method.

Example:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

if (!list.contains("mystring"))
    System.out.println("added string? "+list.add("mystring"));
if (!list.contains("mystring"))
    System.out.println("added string? "+list.add("mystring"));
```

Output:

```
added string? true
added string? false
```

**Pitfall**

Above method works for the basic Java primitives such as `String`, `Double`, `Integer`,... etc. If you have your own objects, you need to overwrite the `hashCode` and `equals` method of your class. Otherwise, the `List#contains` method will test on equality based on the address of the object and not it's content.

Erroneous example:

```
public class Fraction {
    int x, int y;
    public Fraction(int x, int y) { this.x=x;this.y=y;}
}

List<Fraction> fractions = new ArrayList<Fraction>();
Fraction f1 = new Fraction(1,2);

if (!fractions.contains(f1))
    System.out.println("added fraction? "+fractions.add(f1));

if (!fractions.contains(f1))
    System.out.println("added fraction? "+fractions.add(f1));
```

Output:

```
added fraction? true
added fraction? true
```

Fixed example:

```
public class Fraction {
    public int x, int y;
    public Fraction(int x, int y) { this.x=x;this.y=y;}
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o==null) return false;
        if (o==this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Fraction) return false;
        Fraction f = (Fraction) o;
        return f.x == x && f.y ==y;
    }
}

List<Fraction> fractions = new ArrayList<Fraction>();
Fraction f1 = new Fraction(1,2);

if (!fractions.contains(f1))
    System.out.println("added fraction? "+fractions.add(f1));

if (!fractions.contains(f1))
    System.out.println("added fraction? "+fractions.add(f1));
```

Output:

```
added fraction? true
added fraction? false
```

Comment: Ok, how do i use this method? How does it look?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to add something to a container without any duplicates is to use a Set. And if you need the order stay the same you could use an LinkedHashSet implementation.

Then you need to implement an equals method in your class that checks if the items are simular.

In your case I guess that name could be the differing value. Then an equals could be implemented like:

```
 public boolean equals(Object o) {

   // if the object you compare to isn't Kund then they aren't equal.
   if(!(o instanceof Kund)) return false; 

   // return the value of the equals between this object and the object you want     
   // to check equality on. And use the objects name as the field determining if 
   // the values are equal.
   return this.getName().equalsIgnoreCase((Kund)o.getName()); 
 } 

 public int hashCode() {
    return this.getName().hashCode();
 }
```

You also need to implement the hashCode function for your object so that it gets an specific place inside the hashset for lookup by the standard java implementations.